# IntelliJ can't detect openjdk source, even though it's listed in project sources

Tags: intellij-idea, java

Under SDK 1.7 in Project Structure, under the sources tab I have src.zip correctly listed. I've also tried unzipping it and just opening the folder into which it was unzipped.

In both cases I'm unable to actually see the attached source of files in it, e.g., `UnixException.java`.

I've only been able to read this files on grepcode.com but not debug through them.

How do I tell IntelliJ about openjdk source?

Comment: Does the `src.zip` actually contain the `UnixException.java` source file? I didn't think it did.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it sure doesn't. technically you could post that as an answer and I'd accept...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis although I still need to find out how to debug through the unix classes.

Comment: I won't post because I'm not sure, but I think they are restricted by Security Managers. You can always look (maybe decompile) at the `.class` files because those are included in the runtime jars.